# codeigniter database code not working

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am currently a beginner in CodeIgniter, and I am trying to get a simple MVC database thing to work, but it won't.  I'm trying to select a record from a table and display it onto a web page, but I'm getting errors instead.  I will post my code below so you can see what I am working with:

**Model:**

```
function grabData() {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = 1";
    $config['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $config['username'] = "root";
    $config['password'] = "";
    $config['database'] = "bookstore";
    $config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $config['dbprefix'] = "";
    $config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $config['cachedir'] = "";
    $config['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

    // manually connect to database
    $this->load->database($config, TRUE);

    // do some stuff
    $query = $this->db->get('books');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }


}
```

**Controller:**

```
$web['title'] = "CI Hello World App!";
$this->load->view('helloworld_view', $web);

$this->load->model('helloworld_model');
$data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->grabData();

$this->load->view('helloworld_view', $data);
```

**Contents of Table:**

```
1     The Grapes of Wrath            John Steinbeck     12.99
2     Ninteen Eighty-Four            George Orwell      8.99
3     The Wind-Up Bird Chronicle     Haruki Murakami    7.99
```

**Error:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: views/helloworld_view.php

Line Number: 8

null

boolean true
```

I did not display the view because I felt it wasn't the source of the problem.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the query result properly?

Comment: You know you're returning anything of the table content, right? And why are you loading your view twice?

Comment: My view is just a blank web page with the result variable echoed like so:  <?php echo $result; ?>

Comment: @JaPerk14 you have to return the result. refer **tomexsans** answer.

Comment: You cant echo a query resutl since it's an array. use <?php print_r($result) ?> or <?php var_dump($result) ?>

Comment: @MDeSilva yes you can but it will not dispaly the result just a blank Array()

Comment: @sandip, Yes that's what I meant, Who wants to view a blank array? that's why asked to use print_r or var_dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model use this:

```
$query = $this->db->get('books');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

and in controller load view only one time:

```
$data['title'] = "CI Hello World App!";

$this->load->model('helloworld_model');

$data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->grabData();

$this->load->view('helloworld_view', $data);
```

So in view you can access title as `$title` and result as `$result`

Comment: I just noticed this now.  How can I send multiple variables to a single view without loading the same view twice?

Comment: Jut like in above example. $data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->grabData(); $data['title'] = "CI Hello World App!"; etc.........

Comment: you can send multiple variables to a single view using a single array with different variable names like:
$data['title']='something';
$data['page']='something';

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you are not returning anything.

```
$query = $this->db->get('books');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

You are not returning result that's why result is empty on views,

```
$query = $this->db->get('books');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result(); // return a result() or row() or row_array()
} else {
  return false;
}
```

here is a shorthand version 
`return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result() : FALSE;`
this sample will return an `object` read more at

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html